# First letter toUpperCase in js validation into local storage

Tags: javascript, validation, local-storage

I cant figure out how to make the first letter of an input to bet made into uppercase and to appear in local storage.
This is whats going on,
    First Name 
                         
 
Then i have write into local storage and get local storage, then it is displayed,
    Firstname: 
            
So what i want is a javascript validation that will convert the inputs first letter into uppercase and appear in the local storage display page.

Comment: Two many questions. break it up to individual questions and ask for each one.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? If you are using jquery, bind to the input event and change the value to the value with uppercase. Or you can do it just upon submission, if you don't want the change to be displayed in the input itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the first letter of a string upper case by replacing it with its upper case version.

```
function capit(string){
    return string.replace(/[a-z]/i, 
    function(firstletter){
        return firstletter.toUpperCase();
    });
}
```

**capit('rabbit rabbit');**

/*  returned value: (String) Rabbit rabbit */

If you do not use a case insensitive match, the method would make the second letter capitalized if the first letter was upper case already.

You could also ignore non-letters anchored at the start of the string, and so only match a lower case letter if it is not preceeded by a letter.

```
function capit(string){
    return string.replace(/^([^A-Za-z]*)([a-z])/, 
    function(matches, nonletters, firstletter){
        return nonletters+firstletter.toUpperCase();
    });
}
```

**capit('2. rabbit rabbit');**

/*  returned value: (String) 2. Rabbit rabbit */

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
function capitalize(str){
 return str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
}
```

Then if you want to add your string value to `localStorage` you should do this:

```
localStorage.setItem('your key'. capitalize('your value'));
```